# Searching Expandable Listview with onGroupClick & onChildClick showing wrong results

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

i have problem with my onClick after searching in my expandable listview. When i search i get the right results, but when i Toast the values when i click them individually, i get different results? Kindly help

My method to filter my data for search

```
public void filterData(String query){
    query=query.toLowerCase();
    parentRowArrayList.clear();

    if(query.isEmpty()){
        parentRowArrayList.addAll(originalList);
    }else{
        for(ParentRow parentRow:originalList){
            ArrayList<ChildRow> childList = parentRow.getChildList();
            ArrayList<ChildRow> newList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(ChildRow childRow:childList){
                if(childRow.getText().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, childRow.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newList.add(childRow);
                }
            }//end for ChildRow childRow:childList

            if(newList.size()>0){
                ParentRow newParentRow = new ParentRow(parentRow.getName(),newList);

                parentRowArrayList.add(newParentRow);
            }
        } // end for ParentRow parentRow:originalList
    } //end else


    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My OnChildClickListener

```
        myList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                  parentRowArrayList.get(groupPosition).getChildList()
                                          .get(childPosition).getText() +"",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

my OnGroupClickListener

```
   myList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "Group Clicked " + parentRowArrayList.get(groupPosition).getName(),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

SearchView Implemented Methods

```
   @Override
public boolean onClose() {
    listAdapter.filterData("");
    expandAll();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    listAdapter.filterData(query);
    myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    expandAll();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    listAdapter.filterData(query);
    myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    expandAll();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is filterData method part of adapter?

Comment: filterData is in the adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the filterData method is in adapter class and it refers to the same instance member variable(i.e parentRowArrayList) and OnChildClickListener part of your activity so, these two different methods pointing to the two different data sources. If you refer the 'arraylist' from the adapter in  OnChildClickListener method will get the same result.

Comment: so what do i do?

Comment: add getter method in adapter class for parentRowArrayList. Now use it in your click listener methods like `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "Group Clicked " + listAdapter .getparentRowArrayList().get(groupPosition).getName(),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`